# How to mount ignite data to host system

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ignite

I would like to run apache-ignite in docker and I am able to do that.
But the problem is whenever I spin the image and creates the tables in ignite it stays there as long as that container is running. If I restart the container or starts the ignite image again I did not get that data. I know whenever we spins the images it always creates the new container. In my case if I want to persist the data then I need to commit and push the container so that next start I will get it.

But is there any way, where I can store ignite data on host system and whenever I start the image it will read/write the data on that location (in short volume mounting).

Can anyone please share there experience or thought with example?
Thanks.

I am using this with docker-compose and below is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  ignite:
    image: apacheignite/ignite
    environment:
      - IGNITE_QUIET=false
    volumes:
      - "./ignite-main.xml:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/default-config.xml"
    ports:
      - 11211:11211
      - 47100:47100
      - 47500:47500
      - 49112:49112
```

If I run the docker-compose up command then I get the below error.

```
Recreating ignite-test_ignite_1 ... done
Attaching to ignite-test_ignite_1
ignite_1  | Ignite Command Line Startup, ver. 2.7.0#20181130-sha1:256ae401
ignite_1  | 2018 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
ignite_1  | 
ignite_1  | class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context [springUrl=file:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/default-config.xml, err=Line 1 in XML document from URL [file:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/default-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 31; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'property'.]
```

Comment: Please consider moving your solution to answer section.

Comment: Done thanks @alamar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@Update** Hello, After doing lots of RnD I able to solve this issue. Below are the configuration I made 1. docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
    services:
      ignite:
        image: apacheignite/ignite
        environment:
          - IGNITE_QUIET=false

        volumes:
          - ignite-persistence-1:/opt/ignite/
          - "./ignite_1.xml:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/default-config.xml"

        ports:
          - 11211:11211
          - 47100:47100
          - 47500:47500
          - 49112:49112

        deploy:
          replicas: 1
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
            delay: 30s
            max_attempts: 10
            window: 180s

    volumes:
      ignite-persistence-1:
```

2. ignite_1.xml for data persistence

```
               http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

          Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
          distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
          WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
          See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
          limitations under the License.
        -->
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
           <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
              <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
              <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
                 <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                    <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                       <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                          <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true" />
                       </bean>
                    </property>
                 </bean>
              </property>
              <property name="workDirectory" value="/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/data" />
              <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide a list of initial nodes. -->
              <property name="discoverySpi">
                 <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                    <property name="ipFinder">
                       <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                       <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                       <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                          <property name="addresses">
                             <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47502</value>
                             </list>
                          </property>
                       </bean>
                    </property>
                 </bean>
              </property>
           </bean>
        </beans>
```

I kept docker-compose.yml and ignite_1.xml in same directory and opened the terminal from this directory and executed the below command.

**`docker-compose up`**

By using **ignite-persistence-1:/opt/ignite/** I was able to persist the data even if I stop or down the docker-compose.

I hope this will help others as well.

Thanks.